# REACT - Impossible to pop my DIALOG component onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

Good morning everyone,

I am currently losing my calm, on the DIALOG component from Material UI.

At first, I would like to implement a simple DIALOG component apparition when I click on a bin Icon (from MUI library)

So for here is what I've done :

Initiating an open state :

```
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
```

Implement handleOpen and handleClose methods :

```
     const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true)
  }



const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false)
  }
```

Implement my bin Icon in a TableCell :

```
<TableCell>
  <DeleteIcon onClick={() => {handleDeleteUser()}}/>
  <EditIcon onClick={handleUpdateUser}/>
 </TableCell>
```

Pass a Method handleDeleteUser to handle the trigger of the DIALOG box

And then define my handleDeleteUser which is supposed to pop the component and open a Dialog component

Here is the method :

```
const handleDeleteUser = () => {
handleClickOpen()
console.log(open)
return(
  <Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
  >
    <DialogContent>
      <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
        Êtes vous sur de vouloir supprimer cet utilisateur ?
        </DialogContentText>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
      <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
        Oui
        </Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
        Non
        </Button>
    </DialogActions>
  </Dialog>
)
```

}

My issue is the following :

I am able to enter the handleDeleteUser method and I am able to switch the open state from false to true.
Unfortunately, I am not able to return the JSX and so to pop the dialog Box.

As I am a beginner in React and it's my first project using MUI, I am sure it's due to a lack of comprehension of how to use Dialog.

I hope you'll be able to help me!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<Dialog>` template should be present in the render function of the component from the begening. Returning the `JSX` from the `handleDeleteUser` function wouldn't help as it won't append the `Dialog` component to the DOM.

You just need to execute the  `handleClickOpen` function from the `handleDeleteUser` funtion. And the `Dialog` template should already be present in the `render` part to render the dialog.

You may refer to the following sample code-sandbox that uses Dialog: https://codesandbox.io/s/jl06wm10q5

Answer (score 1):

Don't return jsx from the `handleDeleteUser` method. In fact you don't need this method.

```
<TableCell>
  <DeleteIcon onClick={() => handleClickOpen()}/>
  <EditIcon onClick={handleUpdateUser}/>
 </TableCell>
```

Now assign the jsx to a variable

```
const DialogComponent = (
  <Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
  >
    <DialogContent>
      <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
        Êtes vous sur de vouloir supprimer cet utilisateur ?
        </DialogContentText>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
      <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
        Oui
        </Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary" autoFocus>
        Non
        </Button>
    </DialogActions>
  </Dialog>
);
```

And use this variable directly inside the `render/return` method of the parent component function. The variable `open` will automatically hide the dialog and open the dialog for you. You don't need to return it from the function.

```
return (
  {DialogCOmponent}
)
```